# preventDefault doesn't work on pageup or pagedown in Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, preventdefault

I'm working on adding keyboard controls to a datepicker for accessibility. I want to use <kbd>pageup</kbd> and <kbd>pagedown</kbd> keys to toggle between the next and previous months. As part of the code I'm using `e.preventDefault` to prevent the page from being scrolled up or down only when the datepicker is open. I have it working in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome or Safari.

I'm not posting the full code here, but I created test code below. No matter what I try, the page still scrolls up/down when these keys are pressed in Chrome or Safari. I can't use <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, or <kbd>right</kbd> keys because they are used to navigate the focus  between days within each month.

```
$(window).keyup(function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode === 34) {

        console.log('page down');

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
}
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in your example code. Could you please fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple issues with the code.

You can't prevent a default action of a key on `keyup`. By that time the code has already run. It has to be on `keydown`.

The second problem is that the `keyCode` is an integer not a string so your if statement is not going to be entered into.

http://jsfiddle.net/ymr744p4/

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode === 34) {
        console.log('page down');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I typically use keyup, but keydown makes sense now that I understand the order in which keydown, keypress, and keyup occur.